# Is it possible to programmatically add contacts in bulk without going trough the contacts app?

Tags: android

I want to know if it's possible to add multiple contacts at once without interacting with the contacts app in Android (for example: in order to create backup-restore feature for contacts).

According to information I found, in order to add a contact from your own app, you have to create an intent, but this intent will bring the contacts app to the foreground where the user has to confirm.

Comment: See `ContactsContract`.